# Cannot output in Python IDLE after 'reload(sys)'

Tags: python, utf-8, output, python-idle

I've been having difficulties dealing with Chinese characters in python, but apparently adding

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

solved my problems. Well, at least some of them.
Now, I just find out that I cannot send output with `print` or `pprint` on Python IDLE.

I checked my settings of IDLE, and it turned out to be fine.

[image]

However, I can still get the output from PyCharm console.

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I don't have IDLE, so this is guesswork:   "Source Encoding" means the encoding of your `whatever.py` file, not the output of running it.

Comment: Use Python 3.x, especially the most recent versions, and your problems with unicode, or most of them, will go away.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: correct, both reading and writing source files.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, great to know that! Have always been suggested to stuck with Python 2.x for compatibility reasons, but I saw a lot of open source libs provide 3.x support. But then, what does source encoding have to do with what I asked? Wonder if you could kindly explain what you guys were talking about?

Comment: Source encoding does not affect screen display.  Set that aside.  In 2.x, Unicode is an optional add-on with 2 OS-dependent implementations and many bugs that could not be fixed within the old design.  3.0 fixed some problems by making Unicode the central text type.  3.3 fixed more with a new implementation that supports all Unicode chars on all systems in a space efficient manner.  Further fixes have been added since.

Comment: Downvoting for use of `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`. It's totally unnecessary.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thank you! But could you further explain? Because it made an impact on the result. Maybe you can post it as an answer with further explanation? It has bothered me a lot dealing with encoding problems and as you can see, the information I got online are totally flawed.

Comment: @RafaelJ, encoding is a deceptively complex concept that most people (including me) don't give enough thought to, so I understand your frustration. Coming from "simpler" languages which don't bother with encoding (such as PHP), it can seem like an unnecessary hurdle. Python's documentation on Unicode is very good but requires you to read it top to bottom. Once you've read it, you should appreciate that decoding must be applied to any byte string received and encoding applied to anything outputted. For the most part, Python handles encoding when using `print` but it's up to you to do the rest.

Comment: See https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/ for a good explination on why setdefaultencoding is bad. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that IDLE changes the value of `sys.stdout` to redirect output to its window. If you `reload(sys)`, you break this, and the output cannot be seen in IDLE.

There seems to be a bug in Python 2.7 IDLE when it interprets *input*, illustrated here:

```
>>> u'不'
u'\xe4\xb8\x8d'
>>> print u'不'
ä¸
>>> print u'\u4e0d'
不
>>> _
```

As you see, the literal `u'不'` was taken not as a Unicode character, but was first translated to UTF-8 and then these bytes were marked as a Unicode string. No wonder it cannot be printed correctly. If you provide a real Unicode code point, the result prints as expected.

I don't know what to do with IDLE here. I find that Python's REPL in a terminal is nice enough, and running IPython or a Python interpreter from within emacs is even nicer; both are devoid of this bug.

Comment: On Windows, the console interpreter, any version, echos u'不' as '?'.  IDLE, at least for 3.3+, echos '不', as one would want.  So on Windows, IDLE works much better for unicode in the Basic Multilingual Plane.